# How each not-assigned argument of an object prop is known as an independent variable in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prop

I am beginner in React. In one of my exercises I saw the code below for a component:

```js
import React from "react";

const Link = ({ className, href, children }) => {
  const onClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <a onClick={onClick} className={className} href={href}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};

export default Link;
```

As I know from JavaScript, the prop of the `Link` component, is a **single object**. So I expect if we want to use each of its arguments (*for example **className** in my code*) as an independent variable, we have two approach:

1- Using `object`.className as an attribute of the object.

2- Spread the object arguments in separate variables, assign them and then use them independently.

How each argument of object prop is automatically known without assignment as an independent variable in `<a>` tag of my code? Am I misunderstood in sth?

Comment: This is called destructuring; without it you would use `const Link = (props) => ...` and then use `props.href` and so on in your function body / JSX. With destructuring you can extract the props children and set variables at the same time. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment (also, this is not specific to React, which besides JSX is just JavaScript)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for your answer. But in all of the examples for destructuring in a function in the link you introduce, I see assignment!!! As in the code of my question, there is no assignment for object arguments!

Comment: Ok, but does it matter? It still works the same way. Here's an article about it: https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6